# Jenkins Parameter to Terraform variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, terraform

I'm trying to set up Jenkins as a mini portal. User starts a parameterized build and selects a region from a dropdown.

What I am missing (do not know if it's possible) is how I would pass the parameter in the build to terraform so it can build the infrastructure in that region?

UserA starts a pipeline build, selects US East, terraform deploys infra in that region.

UserB starts pipeline build, selects US East 2, terraform deploys infra in that region.

I believe the terraform jenkin plugin can handle this, but it only works as a freestyle project. I am trying to do this via a pipeline.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are specifically about AWS regions, you can just configure the environment variable `AWS_REGION` and Terraform will respect it.

Terraform variables can be specified from the command line via `-var`:

```
terraform plan -var region=eu-west-1
```

In Jenkins, you can access parameters via `params`. The result in a pipeline (with a parameter called `region`) would be something like:

```
sh "terraform plan -var region=${params.region}"
```

Comment: would it be similar for azure?

Comment: With the `-var` it would be the same. With the environment variable, it seems that `ARM_ENVIRONMENT` is the pendant (if I understand the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/index.html#environment) right).